# Converting json to pdf using js frameworks

Tags: javascript

I want to convert json data into a pdf file via client-side Javascript. Can you please point me in a helpful direction?

For example, I'd like to convert this json

```
{"employees":[
    {"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"}, 
    {"firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith"},
    {"firstName":"Peter", "lastName":"Jones"}
]}
```

Into a pdf...

```
Employees

FirstName: John  LastName  :Doe

FirstName: Anna LastName  :Smith

FirstName: Peter LastName  :Jones
```

Comment: JSON data to pdf? What does that even mean?

Comment: updated with what I want to do

Answer (score 17):

You can generate PDF's on the client using [jsPDF](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF) .

```
var employees = [
    {"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"}, 
    {"firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith"},
    {"firstName":"Peter", "lastName":"Jones"}
];

var doc = new jsPDF();
employees.forEach(function(employee, i){
    doc.text(20, 10 + (i * 10), 
        "First Name: " + employee.firstName +
        "Last Name: " + employee.lastName);
});
doc.save('Test.pdf');
```

Comment: I have to do same thing but my json object is big which is a table basically with more than 800 entries how I can do it

Comment: I guess it does not matter how many entries you have, the approach would be the same, or am i missing something ?

Comment: As an alternative, you can also try the [pdfmake](http://pdfmake.org/#/) library.

Comment: How can we generate table like structure through jsPDF?

Answer (score 7):

You can use [pdfmake](https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake) which support both client side and server side rendering

```
//import pdfmake
import pdfMake from 'pdfmake/build/pdfmake.js';
import pdfFonts from 'pdfmake/build/vfs_fonts.js';

pdfMake.vfs = pdfFonts.pdfMake.vfs;

const employees = [
    {"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"}, 
    {"firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith"},
    {"firstName":"Peter", "lastName":"Jones"}
];
const document = { content: [{text: 'Employees', fontStyle: 15, lineHeight: 2}] }
employees.forEach(employee => {
    document.content.push({
        columns: [
            { text: 'firstname', width: 60 },
            { text: ':', width: 10 },
            { text:employee.firstName, width: 50 },
            { text: 'lastName', width: 60 },
            {text: ':', width: 10 }, { text: employee.lastName, width: 50}
        ],
        lineHeight: 2
    });
});
pdfMake.createPdf(document).download();
```