# Export data and Fixed Data Table

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, fixed-data-table

I use Fixed Data Grid in my project.

https://facebook.github.io/fixed-data-table/example-sort.html

I want to take csv and pdf reports.
Is it possible to export grid data to pdf or csv directly?
Or what can I do to take csv and pdf reports with data provider(JSON Array) of datagrid?

Comment: I haven't been able to find any built in csv export option in this module but for the CSV export I just built my own very quickly.  
You already have the data that you're providing to the component, all you have to do is write a function that organizes the data into csv format.  Put a button on the table and onClick invoke the function.  For building the csv exporting here is a guide: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14964035/how-to-export-javascript-array-info-to-csv-on-client-side

Answer (score 2):

Since you have access to the raw JSON data that gets displayed within the table, you should be able to use a library like [Papa Parse](http://papaparse.com/) to ["unparse" the data](http://papaparse.com/#unparse) into a csv format, which can then be downloaded.

As for converting to pdf, I would look into the [jsPDF library](https://parall.ax/products/jspdf). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26969514/converting-json-to-pdf-using-js-frameworks/#26969576) for details about how to do that.