# How to export my json data into pdf,excel using angular 2

Tags: angular, angularjs-directive, primeng

I have created my Data table from the **angular 2** website. Now I want to export my json data to PDF,excel using angular 2 framework.

Kindly give me suggestion how can I achieve that or any link if you have.

Regards

Comment: Do you want use plugins?

Comment: https://medium.com/@darilldrems/angularjs-export-html-table-to-pdf-excel-or-doc-formats-bb741d06dfec#.ll3d5jtlc
this might be what you are looking for.
Otherwise you could sned the data via a request to something like php and process it there.

Answer (score 0):

Use [jsPDF](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF) to convert from JSON to PDF.

And [AlaSQL](https://github.com/agershun/alasql) to convert from JSON to Excel (*.xls, *.xlsx).

Answer (score 0):

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('ngJsonExportExcel', [])
        .directive('ngJsonExportExcel', function () {

            return {
                restrict: 'AE',
                scope: {
                    data : '=',
                    filename: '=?',
                    reportFields: '=',
                    separator: '@'
                },

                link: function (scope, element) {
                    scope.filename = !!scope.filename ? scope.filename : 'SalesReport';

                    var fields = [];
                    var header = [];
                    var separator = scope.separator || ',';

                    angular.forEach(scope.reportFields, function(field, key) {
                        if(!field || !key) {
                            throw new Error('error json report fields');
                        }

                        fields.push(key);
                        header.push(field);
                    });

                    element.bind('click', function() {
                        var bodyData = _bodyData();
                        var strData = _convertToExcel(bodyData);

                        var blob = new Blob([strData], {type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8"});

                        return saveAs(blob, [scope.filename + '.csv']);
                    });

                    function _bodyData() {
                        var data = scope.data;
                        var body = "";
                        angular.forEach(data, function(dataItem) {
                            var rowItems = [];

                            angular.forEach(fields, function(field) {
                                if(field.indexOf('.')) {
                                    field = field.split(".");
                                    var curItem = dataItem;

                                    // deep access to obect property
                                    angular.forEach(field, function(prop){
                                        if (curItem !== null && curItem !== undefined) {
                                            curItem = curItem[prop];
                                        }
                                    });

                                    data = curItem;
                                }
                                else {
                                    data = dataItem[field];
                                }

                                var fieldValue = data !== null ? data : ' ';

                                if (fieldValue !== undefined && angular.isObject(fieldValue)) {
                                    fieldValue = _objectToString(fieldValue);
                                }

                                if(typeof fieldValue == 'string') {
                                    rowItems.push('"' + fieldValue.replace(/"/g, '""') + '"');
                                } else {
                                    rowItems.push(fieldValue);
                                }
                            });

                            body += rowItems.join(separator) + '\n';
                        });

                        return body;
                    }

                    function _convertToExcel(body) {
                        return header.join(separator) + '\n' + body;
                    }

                    function _objectToString(object) {
                        var output = '';
                        angular.forEach(object, function(value, key) {
                            output += key + ':' + value + ' ';
                        });

                        return '"' + output + '"';
                    }
                }
            };
        });
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should look for how to export your `data-table` to a `JSON` format object then there is plenty of examples how to convert a JSON to PDF/CSV and could be used in native `JavaScript` or `TypeScript`.
Those links may help you:
[Converting json to pdf using js frameworks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26969514/converting-json-to-pdf-using-js-frameworks) and
http://jsfiddle.net/hybrid13i/JXrwM/

Answer (score 0):

I was finally used this one:

```
    function downloadExcelFile(ev) {
        connectionService.getExcelExport(function (response) {
            if (response.status == 200) {

                /** 
                 * Export data to csv file
                 */
                let blob = new Blob([response.data], {type: 'text/csv'});
                let filename = `export.csv`;
                if(window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
                    window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, filename);
                }
                else{
                    let elem = window.document.createElement('a');
                    elem.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                    elem.download = filename;
                    document.body.appendChild(elem);
                    elem.click();
                    document.body.removeChild(elem);
                }

                console.log(`export excel file is successful.`);
            }
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I can answer your question partially so that you can export your `JSON` data to `excel`. You can use [XLSX](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx) library for `Angular 2+`.

Assuming your `JSON` data will be something like what assigned to `readyToExport` and hence it is shown how to export your `JSON` data.

```
public export() {
const readyToExport = [
  {id: 1, name: 'a', address: 'x'},
  {id: 2, name: 'b', address: 'y'},
  {id: 3, name: 'c', address: 'z'}
];

const workBook = XLSX.utils.book_new(); // create a new blank book
const workSheet = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(readyToExport);

XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(workBook, workSheet, 'data'); // add the worksheet to the book
XLSX.writeFile(workBook, 'temp.xlsx'); // initiate a file download in browser
}
```