# How can i download my json resume as pdf on my gist?

Tags: json, pdf, github, resume, gist

I want to download my json-resume as pdf file with intended theme .

https://gist.github.com/ertugdlk/45c7cccb43e66714a90cdfb8fae5ea56

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26969514/converting-json-to-pdf-using-js-frameworks) answer, hopefully it can help.

Comment: thanks ill check it

Comment: Hey @phybarin, creator of jsonresume here, can you create an issue on the github repo. For now try just printing to pdf in chrome

Answer (score 2):

**Steps:**

1. Create an empty folder
2. Add your resume.json file to the folder
3. In VS-Code, open/cd into the folder
4. Open the terminal
5. *enter*: npm init -y
6. *enter*: npm install
7. *enter*: npm install resume-cli
8. enter: npm install jsonresume-theme-**YOURTHEMEHERE** (ex: elegant)
9. enter: resume export --format pdf --theme **YOURTHEMEHERE**
   resume.pdf

**The oldest answer to this question was a bit vague so I decided to clarify.**

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the resume-cli using **npm install -g resume-cli**.
Then run the command **resume export --format pdf resume.pdf**.  If you use one of the custom themes, you need to use **npm install -g jsonresume-theme-**.  After installing the theme you can use **resume export --format pdf --theme  resume.pdf**